# Responsive images with different sizes on same level

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Hello i would like to get same row size of images as it is on example, but you can see that when you change size of window, bigger images are smaller than columns on left.
I am fighting with it for a long time, and still didnt found solution. I need to have it with overlay text. So this is another problem. Thank you for any sugestions
http://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/264/

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
<div class="small-3 columns col-left" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" /> 
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="small-3 columns col-left" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" /> 
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/600x645" /> 
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/600x645" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have viewed the demo, but I could not able to understand the problem.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/izLwI45wUM i need this.

Comment: So, you want bottom edge of photos to be at the same level?

Comment: same bottom, top edge on responsive page.

Answer (score 1):

the issue comes from the padding

```
.col-left img:last-child {
    padding-top:1em;
}
```

when resizing the window, only the blocks are getting resized, the top padding is maintained

I recommend using a percentage there, in this particular case 8% seems to do the trick

```
.col-left img:last-child {
    padding-top:8%;
}
```

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/7cfa540c9fe926c2e72142b8cd566c94.png its not working on real size :/